# Compare the second index of the string with the second index of the next string in the array string

Tags: java

I am trying to compare the second index of the string with the second index of next string also I have also to compare the string with the next one to find the postion `08:10, 18:40` where the time difference is greater than 45 min and then increment the time string until the difference is less than 45 min.

How can I compare two string in the string array to find the right position `08:10, 18:40` in the array string ?

**Simple:**

```
[04:31, 05:09, 05:39, 06:09, 06:39, 07:10, 07:40, 08:10, 18:40, 19:10, 20:40, 21:10, 22:25, 23:40]
```

**Code:**

```
String[] tokens = split_line(line);

for(String time: tokens ){
    int hour = Character.getNumericValue(time.charAt(1));
    System.out.println(time);
}
```

Comment: There isn't much of a way to answer this question without just writing the code for you, but I'd suggest starting by writing a function which extracts the minute portion of the strings and converts them into ints, and then writing another routine which iterates over your array in the manner you need (hard to tell exactly what you're asking in this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple approach is to convert your values to `int`s representing the minute from midnight that corresponds to the string. For example, `"04:31"` would become 271 (4*60+31), and `"18:40"` would become 1120.

A straightforward implementation of this would use `split` on a colon `:` character to get `["18", "40"]`, and then using [`parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) on both parts.

After that all you need to do is searching for positions of `int`s that are more than 45 minutes apart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try to implement it and post my answer here later and then marked the answer. What does `S` after int mean in your answer?

Comment: @TheBook ints is plural for an `int`. It looks separate from `int` because of code mark-up.

Comment: I have converted the list to integer list (also minutes) how can I compare the first value with the second  and the second with the third ... to calculate the difference?

Comment: @TheBook Use a loop on `i` from zero to `n-1`, and compare integers at indexes `i` and `i+1`.